# How do you retrieve a dojox.mobile widget in a html file from a js file using worklight

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I created a Icon menu on my first swap view with multiple IconMenuItems.  This is a snipet of the code.  How do I manipulate the individual IconMenutItems from the JS file?  I tried both retrievals of the first IconMenutItem resulting in the retrieval of a [object HTMLLIElement] instead of the IconMenuItem.  Even with a call to the button.label or button.title it came back as undefined.  Is it possible to manipulate a specific dojo item after it is created?  Sorry if this is a beginner question, I am very new to both Worklight and Dojo

HTML:

```
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SwapView"id="MainPageView"
    data-dojo-props="selected:true">
        <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenu" id="menu"
        style="width: 320px; height: 400px;" data-dojo-props="cols: 3">
            <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenuItem"label="empty"
            onclick=handleButton(this) id="btn1" title="title1"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    var button1= document.getElementById("btn1");
    WL.Logger.debug(""+button1.label);

    var button2= dojo.query("#btn1");
    WL.Logger.debug(""+button2.label);*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `dijit/registry`

```
require(['dijit/registry'], function(registry) {
    var btn1 = registry.byId("btn1");
});
```

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/GyzXG/

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html

Comment: I am getting the same results as the other two retrievals.  btn1 is a HTMLLIElement and its label is undefined.  How would I go about manipulating the label on the original IconMenuItem's label?

Comment: Are you sure that the html is being parsed by the parser?

Comment: Yeah, I included the line "<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>" within the html head

Comment: Does registry.toArray() contain any widgets?  My guess is that there is an error on parsing.  Does your mobile browser have a console that will show javascript errors?

Comment: Yeah it contains all the widgets that I created within the html file.  The mobile browser's console is not showing any javascript errors when I run the code.  When I debug the code within the require statement that you gave me it works great!  Does this mean that any changes to the widgets need to be done within the require statement?

Comment: You need the require statement in order to be able to use the dijit/registry module. Also, you would need to ensure that your call of registry.byId() is done once the parsing is finished. For that, see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/ready.html (the first code example covers your case using parseOnLoad).